# Fill NSArray with NSFetchRequest => [array count] wrong

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsfetchrequest

I have a custom `NSManagedObject` which has several properties. I `alloc` and `init` two instances of the object: `compare1` & `compare2`. Then I do a `NSFetchRequest` to get two of these custom objects and fill their properties in an `NSArray` structure to display them in a `UITableView` later.

My problem is, that the `UITableView` crashes. I did some research in the code and found out, that sometimes the array does not have the full count. When I play with my sliders and text field it works sometimes, but it is (at least for me) not reproducable.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT: The problem is clear now. The `object description` is complete. I transfer it to an `NSArray` via `NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: object.value1, ..., nil];`. Now the strange thing: `[array count]` gives me a wrong number? Only the values which are `!= 0` are in the array. Why so? Thank you!**

Here is the code of the `NSFetchRequest`:

```
-(NSArray *)performFetch
{

if (__managedObjectContext == nil)
{
    __managedObjectContext = [(MasterViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

NSError *error = nil;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSLog(@"FetchedObjects Count: %i", [fetchedObjects count]); //always right

compare1 = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0]; //compare is a custom NSObject
compare2 = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:1]; //with several properties (.1 to .17)

NSLog(@"%@",[compare1 description]); //is complete
NSLog(@"%@",[compare2 description]); //is complete

NSArray * valuesS1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:compare1.1,__andsoon__compare1.14, nil];

NSArray * valuesB1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:compare1.14__andsoon__compare1.17, nil];


NSArray * valuesS2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:compare2.1,__andsoon__compare2.14, nil];

NSArray * valuesB2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:compare2.14__andsoon__compare2.17, nil];


NSMutableArray * valuesArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:valuesS1, valuesB1, nil];
NSMutableArray * valuesArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:valuesS2, valuesB2, nil];


compareArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:valuesArray1, valuesArray2, nil];

NSLog(@"Array1 count: %i",[values1 count]); //sometimes (I don't know why)
NSLog(@"Array2 count: %i",[values2 count]); //[values1 count] != [values2 count]

return compareArray; //sometimes returns an array with too less objects so my UITableView crashes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the values which are != 0 are in the array

You can't add `nil` values directly to an array. (`nil` is usually zero.) If you need to add "empty" values to an array you need to check and insert an `NSNull` value instead. For example:

```
NSArray * valuesS1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:val1 ? val1 : [NSNull null], val2 ? val2 : [NSNull null], nil];
```

**Edit**

The `?:` is equivalent to:

```
if (val1) {
  return val1;
}
else {
  return [NSNull null];
}
```

If you want to use `@"0"` instead of `NSNull` you can; it can be anything you like as long as it's an object and is not `nil`.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This sounds to be a good start, but could you maybe give me your example as a pseudocode so I better understand the code? Can I also give the zero as a `NSString` to the Array? In your code it would be something like: `...initWithObjects:val1 ? val1 : [@"0"], val2 ...` Is this possible? Because I reuse the values to give the initial value for some sliders and now I'm doing this via `slider.value = [object.property intValue]`

Comment: This one was nice! Thank you! Just to be complete to all who also want to add a `NSString`: `NSArray * valuesS1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:val1 ? val1 : [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0"], nil];`

Comment: You can just do: `NSArray * valuesS1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:val1 ? val1 : @"0", nil];`. The `stringWithFormat:` part is unnecessary.